# Алгоритм Беллмана - Форда

Tags: графы, алгоритм

Здравствуйте, опишите, пожалуйста, пошагово этот алгоритм, давать ссылки не надо, читал на разных сайтах - все равно не понял. Спасибо.

Comment: и какова вероятность того, что сейчас поймёте?

Comment: Если будет обьяснено пошагово и подробно, то вероятность высока.

Comment: Очень сомневаюсь, что кто-то даст лучшее объяснение, чем в Кормене. Еще хуже, если вам что-то скажут неправильно.

Comment: Например я находил 2 разные реализации или даже 3.В голове каша.

Comment: @lcome_back Алгоритм - *это не его реализация,* тем более реализации на сайтах типа `algolist` обычно не отличаются качеством. Ищите [короткий и лаконичный псевдокод алгоритма] (с пошаговым описанием работы). Дальше, при желании, разбирайтесь с доказательством корректности.

[1]: http://books.google.ru/books?id=NLngYyWFl_YC&lpg=PA639&ots=BxRrCy6fB5&dq=bellman%20ford%20algorithm%20cormen&hl=ru&pg=PA589#v=onepage&q=bellman%20ford%20algorithm%20cormen&f=false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этот алгоритм довольно прост: на каждом шаге цикла мы пытаемся выполнить *релаксацию* через каждое ребро – пусть ребро из **A** —> **B**, тогда, если [расстояние до **А**] + **AB** < [расстояние до **B**], то мы можем улучшить путь до **B**, пройдя в **A** и далее по нашему ребру. В принципе, достаточно просто проверять на каждой итерации, что была ли на ней  хоть одна релаксация, или нет: если не было, то дальше бегать бесполезно, лучший путь из ниоткуда не появится, можно выходить из цикла. Интуитивно понятно, что цикл конечен: мы не можем "вечно" улучшать путь, если можем – в графе отрицательный цикл, а это отдельный случай. Докажем, что, при отсутствии циклов отрицательной длинны, число итераций цикла не более V - 1, где V – число вершин. Заметим, что при 1 итерации, мы определяем все лучшие пути длинны 1, при 2 итерации – все лучшие пути длинны 2 и т.д. Пути в графе из V вершин без их повторения длиннее V - 1 быть не может, значит, делать больше V - 1 итерации бессмысленно.

Еще рекомендую посмотреть [здесь](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/ford_bellman), там есть и про отрицательные циклы.